# Visual Studio Mac replacing (corrupting) file contents.

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Since I loaded build 1868 of VisualStudio for Mac, it has been randomly replacing the contents of an open tab with the contents of another open tab. If I don't notice and compile, it will then save those contents to both files which basically destroys one of my source files.

I loaded v. 7.7.1 (build 15) hoping they snuck a fix for the problem in there. If anything, now it's worse. I'm having to close and re-open VS every 15 minutes, or so, and digging up a backup to repair a corrupted file every couple of hours (when I don't notice and it overwrites a file).

This is REALLY slowing me down. I haven't been able to find anyone else complaining about this, which makes me wonder if it's just me?

I'm running on macOS Sierra (v. 10.12.6). I'm using Xamarin to develop a mobile application, and am currently focusing on the Android side (and will get back to iOS eventually).

Does anyone have any ideas why this may be happening? Do you have any advice besides remove then reload everything? Sure it's an easy answer, but takes a very long time to do with less than awesome internet speed.

Thanks in advance for your help!
-Karen

Comment: Ok, you can submit a question via VS for mac here(https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/41/index.html). If the submission is successful, please tell me the link.

Comment: I sure did submit it! https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/411730/compile-errors-in-non-active-tabs-can-corrupt-the.html

I finally figured out a repeatable way to reproduce it, so there it is. It has to do with having a compiler error in a different tab. When VS tries to take you to that error, it doesn't switch tabs. Now that I know what's causing it, it's somewhat easy to work around, but annoying as all heck.

Comment: Ok,glad to know that you already submitted.Your repeatable way is good,you can try that.Xamarin will try to solve this issue,if solved it will be very convenient.

Comment: I have one piece of advice. Your comment "digging up a backup to repair a corrupted file", suggests that you are not using Git or another version control system such as svn. If that is true, you should start using one (probably git).

Comment: No matter where your backups are, you still have to dig them up. My colloquialism in no way suggests that we don't use a version control system, and using one does not make this problem any less painful.

Comment: Hint: I noticed that using SaveAll also corrupts the tabs, so I've been saving each file individually before compiling, and have not had the problem today. This might be a viable workaround.

Comment: Just lost an days worth of code. Fix this Microsoft.

Comment: Just thought I'd give a quick update. I am now running Version 8.0.5 (Build 9) which contains the "fix" for this bug. I don't believe it is completely fixed. I have caught it changing the names in one of my tabs a couple of times. Keep saving your files individually, folks.